# How are the motor ratings required for a load calculated?

Tags: motor, load

I want to calculate how much weight can be carried by dc shunt motor. Until now I did have not tried to do so, but I have lab experience in applying a braking load. I would like to know how a moving load like an electric cycle is calculated.

Comment: How much can a truck haul? Depends on the size of the truck

Answer (score 1):

This is a mechanical engineering problem. You must determine a convenient motor shaft speed based on wheel diameter, maximum desired vehicle speed and mechanical speed reduction that is not too difficult or inefficient. Then convert the sum of the torque reflected to the motor shaft by all mechanical loads elements such as rolling friction, drive train friction, aerodynamic drag, force required to accelerate inertia at the desired rate and force required to raise mass up an incline. The motor power output rating is shaft speed multiplied by shaft torque with the result multiplied by a constant required by the units of power, speed and torque. Motors manufactured to international standards are rated by output mechanical power and shaft speed. Inexpensive motors sold by non-English speaking sellers providing descriptions in English are often presented with undefined and inconsistent specifications.

Comment: I recall a more detailed answer provided for a similar question, but I can't find it.

Comment: A DC shunt motor is not a good choice of motor for any purpose. The most recent significant use of wound-field DC motors has been electronically controlled separately-excited motors, but they have not been favored for new designs in recent years. The use of universal motors is also declining. Permanent-magnet brushed DC motors have significant use for fixed-speed battery operation, but brushless motors are favored for speed-controlled applications.

Comment: Please recommend me what motor should ues for electrical cycle

Comment: A 3-phase, permanent-magnet, synchronous motor, also known as a 3-phase brushless DC motor is likely to be best.

Comment: Thank you sir for spending valuable time for giving answer.